# Disable postback in paging (gridviewcontrol)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a GridView with paging enabled. When I select a different page in the GridView control, it causes a postback. Because of that my binding of data doesn't occur.

How is it possible to disable postback in paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to do the paging with out pager on grid view, and to do paging you need to postback page.

If you dont want pager than remove it by Setting `AllowPagaing= false` property in gridview control.

Comment: is there any other way to retain data after postback

Comment: @saurabh goyal -- not getting you but if you want to retain viewsate will do the task for you otherwise you can bind the data again

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to include your Page Load code inside

```
if (!IsPsotBack)
{}
```

So that will not be executed on postback fired from grid's paging event